# Style lost when combining workbooks with aspose

Tags: java, excel, aspose, aspose-cells

When combining many Excel files with aspose, I get a single workbook (Excel file with many sheets). But the problem is that I don't get the HTML style(color, font, size background color...) which was in each sheet before the merge.

Here is my java code:

```
 import com.aspose.cells.*;

  public static void main(String args[]){

        Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
        Workbook introductionWorkbook = new Workbook("reports/introduction.xlsx");
        Workbook conclusionWorkbook = new Workbook("reports/conclusion.xlsx");
        
        workbook.combine(introductionWorkbook);
        workbook.combine(conclusionWorkbook); 

        //save the merged file
        workbook.save("/reports/merged_file.xlsx");
}
```

I don't know if there is an option to make aspose take into consideration the style when combining workbooks?

For example, I have a text like this is my Excel sheet before it get merged

[image]

After it get merged, it become like this

[image]

Comment: Please download and try the latest version of Aspose.Cells for Java. It should fix your issue. But if your issue still occurs, then please post your question in Aspose.Cells forum with your source excel file(s) that you have used in your sample code. We will replicate the issue and log it in our database for a fix.

Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: I'm already working with the last version of aspose , 
    <version>16.11.0</version>

Comment: Thank you, then please post your issue in cells forum if you like.

Answer (score 2):

Downloaded the latest version(aspose-cells-17.02.0-java.zip) from [here](https://www.aspose.com/products/cells/java) and it looks working fine.

[image]